# Laravel resource route with name gives error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I followed a tutorial to add middleware checking if a user is admin when loading a page. It works for normal view routes, e.g.

```php
Route::get('/admin/something', 'AdminController@admin_something')
    ->middleware('is_admin')
    ->name('admin');
```

But I now have a resource route and get an error when I add the name and middleware to the route. So this works with no auth:

```php
Route::resource('thingies', 'ThingyController');
```

But with this:

```php
Route::resource('thingies', 'ThingyController')
    ->middleware('is_admin')
    ->name('admin');
```

I get an error:

> ```
> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
> Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::name(),
>   1 passed in /var/www/routes/web.php on line 24 and exactly 2 expected
> ```

What do I need to do differently to add this auth to a resource route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't name your route *"admin"* with `->name('admin');` at the end of your resource route because it concerns all CRUD routes in one statement and Laravel build-in system has already named them.

You're on the good way, just delete the last line like so, it should works :

`Route::resource('thingies', 'ThingyController')
->middleware('is_admin');`

Comment: Thanks for this - it got rid of that error but gave a new one instead! "Call to a member function isAdmin() on null". I've added the function it refers to (from the linked tutorial) to my question.

Comment: After reading the tutorial, actually it isn't the function's declaration that you posted but the class middleware which use it..
Are you using Tinker to test this ?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant (getting used to the terminology still). This is the bit the error page refers to. Updated question to clarify.

I haven't tested with Tinker. I'm using Laradock (Docker container) to serve the site and I can access Artisan inside the container if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for editing, the problem here is that the call to auth()->user() return null in your testing, are you sure about your user entry in DB ?

Comment: Oh yeah I have an admin user in there. I actually made a bunch of test users with a whole load of different values in the 'type' column but I guess that wouldn't have broken it? It does work properly for the other routes (normal view routes).

Comment: Sorry, to clarify - this is when not logged in. Your initial answer seems to have fixed it for when logged in, so this is just what is being returned when not logged in (when of course it should be a 404 or home page or something).

Comment: Nice ! We just go further so.

For now, simply add this if statement on your isAdmin() function : 

`public function isAdmin() {
  if($this === null) {
    return redirect('home');
}
return $this->type === self::ADMIN_TYPE;
}`

This should do the trick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181204/discussion-between-jeuneapprenti-and-sam).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot give a 'name' to a `resource route`. but you can give names to each method in the `resource controller` separately.

to do so `name()` function required 2 parameters.

1. method name
2. name for that method route.

,

```
Route::resource('thingies', 'ThingyController')
    ->middleware('is_admin')
    ->name('create', 'admin.create');
```

Comment: Thanks, this also solves the first error but gives me "Call to a member function isAdmin() on null". I've added the function it refers to (from the linked tutorial) to my question. I'm also not 100% clear on how I'd proceed with this fix - would I add a new route for each CRUD function?